# Mount block device on boot using systemd in coreos

Tags: mount, boot, systemd, coreos

I am mounting `/dev/vdb1` to `/media/esdata` using the following systemd unit:

The unit is located at `/etc/systemd/system/media-esdata.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount cinder volume
Before=docker.service
[Mount]
What=/dev/vdb1
Where=/media/esdata
Options=defaults,noatime,noexec
```

but this does not get started on reboot. I cannot seem to enable this unit either:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable media-esdata.mount
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

What can I do to always have `/media/esdata` available?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [Install] field in the media-esdata.mount, `systemctl enable` will create the link for you:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount cinder volume
Before=docker.service

[Mount]
What=/dev/vdb1
Where=/media/esdata
Options=defaults,noatime,noexec

[Install]
WantedBy=docker.service
```

When enabling the mount unit, you should see the following message:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable media-esdata.mount
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/docer.service.wants/media-esdata.mount → /etc/systemd/system/media-esdata.mount.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "enable" this unit, which means it starts on boot. You can do this via cloud-config or manually with `sudo systemctl enable media-esdata.mount`

Comment: This gave me an error about missing an `[Install]` section.

Answer (score 0):

My work around was to `systemctl enable docker.service` and then create a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.wants` and symlink the `media-esdata.mount` in to that folder. Systemd was willing to start `docker.service` on boot and using the folder wants it forced the drive to be mounted.

Now I have docker running without having SSH in to the box and run `docker` (which by default is only started when the `docker.socket` dependency is triggered. Plus, I get the drive mounted before any container could access the file system. Not exactly straight-forward but it works reliably and doesn't seem to far off the beaten path.